# Enumerate QML properties in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtcore, qmetaobject

Im doing the following to render a QML in my Qt embedded app:

```
QDeclarativeView *view = new QDeclarativeView(this);
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("dial.qml"));
view->show();
QObject *dial = view->rootObject();
```

Is there a way i can enumerate all the property values defined in the root item?

For example, if i have the QML:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
Item {
  id: root
  property real dial_value : 0
  property real dial_length: 0
  property real background_opacity: 1
  etc, etc
}
```

Is there a Qt method that will end up with me having a list of these strings:

```
dial_value
dial_length
background_opacity
```

Ive tried, the following, but it the list is empty:

```
QList<QByteArray> list = dial->dynamicPropertyNames();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried dial->metaObject->property(index); in a loop with the propertyCount() method and then the name() method?

Comment: That will do it! Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dial->metaObject->propertyCount(); ++i) {
    QMetaProperty metaProperty = dial->metaobject()->property(i);
    qDebug() << metaProperty.name();
}
```